# How the getInstance() method works and why the new keyword is not used?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, instance, instantiation

I noticed that the `new` keyword is not used when creating the reference to the instance. Here's the code snippet:

```
public class SingletonExample {
    private static SingletonExample instance;

    private SingletonExample() {
        // Private constructor
        System.out.println("SingletonExample instance created.");
    }

    public static SingletonExample getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SingletonExample();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void displayMessage() {
        System.out.println("Hello from SingletonExample!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This won't work : SingletonExample instance = new SingletonExample();

        // Getting an instance of SingletonExample using getInstance() method
       SingletonExample singleton = SingletonExample.getInstance();
        singleton.displayMessage();
        
    }
}
```

I expected that creating a new instance of a class would involve using the `new` keyword, but it appears that the `getInstance()` method handles this without it. I'm looking for an explanation of why the `new` keyword is omitted in this scenario and how the instance is actually created using the `getInstance()` method.

Can someone provide insights into how the `getInstance()` method works in this context and why the `new` keyword is not used?

Comment: Look at the `getInstance()` method again. It *does* use `new` to create a new `SingletonExample`.

Comment: Also, `new SingletonExample()` *would* actually work in the code you've given, because your `main` method is within the `SingletonExample` class... ideally your example would show it in a different class.

Answer (score 2):

`getInstance()` actually returns an instance of previously created and saved to a variable the instance of a class with the `new` operator.

```
public static SingletonExample getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new SingletonExample();
                   ^^^
    }
    return instance;
}
```

---

[**Instantiating a class**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

> The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.
>
> Note: The phrase "instantiating a class" means the same thing as "creating an object." When you create an object, you are creating an "instance" of a class, therefore "instantiating" a class.
> The new operator requires a single, postfix argument: a call to a constructor. The name of the constructor provides the name of the class to instantiate.
>
> The new operator returns a reference to the object it created. This reference is usually assigned to a variable of the appropriate type, like:
>
> Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
> The reference returned by the new operator does not have to be assigned to a variable. It can also be used directly in an expression. For example:
>
> int height = new Rectangle().height;
> This statement will be discussed in the next section.